# Converting from <day> <time> to DateTime in python and Django, and back

Tags: python, django, datetime, strptime

Im trying to use strptime to convert a day and time into a DateTime field. That is, convert input like "Friday 3:00 PM" to a datetime field. The event this is for takes place over three consecutive days, so I know that Friday will be a specific day in February, and so on.

My question, is how do I go about doing this? How do I convert, for example, Friday 3:00 PM into 2017-02-24 15:00:00?

What I have right now in my Django project, in views.py is:

```
new_request.start = time.strptime(form.cleaned_data['start'], '%A %I:%M %p')
```

Then, I have to print out "Friday 3:00 PM" from the datetime field later, using strftime, which I would assume is the reverse of the above?

Thanks!

Comment: You do not have year in your date "Friday 3:00 PM", you need it if you want to convert it to something like "2017-02-24 15:00:00"

Comment: I know what the year will be though

Comment: Means year is fixed to 2017?

Comment: In this case yes, but there's a function that returns the year that the even will be in

Comment: Take a look at the answer below and let me know if that's what you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adapt the example below to achieve what you want exactly:

```
import time

time.strftime("%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S", time.strptime('Friday 3 February 2017 3:00PM', '%A %d %B %Y %I:%M%p'))
# Output: '2017-03-02 15:00:00'
```

If year and month are fixed to 2017 and February like you mentioned then "Friday 3:00 PM" can be converted as follows:

```
time.strftime("2017-%d-2 %H:%M:%S", time.strptime('Friday 3 3:00PM', '%A %d %I:%M%p'))
# Output: '2017-03-2 15:00:00'
```

If you want to get `datetime` object use the following:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.strptime('Friday 3 February 2017 3:00PM', '%A %d %B %Y %I:%M%p')
# Output: datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 3, 15, 0)
```

Comment: This should do it! Thanks so much!

Comment: Just edited my answer to include an example of creating `datetime` object from string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [python-dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/) to parse readable time string to datetime object. It's very convenient and easy to use.

Examples from its document page:

```
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import *
>>> from dateutil.easter import *
>>> from dateutil.rrule import *
>>> from dateutil.parser import *
>>> from datetime import *
>>> now = parse("Sat Oct 11 17:13:46 UTC 2003")
>>> today = now.date()
>>> year = rrule(YEARLY,dtstart=now,bymonth=8,bymonthday=13,byweekday=FR)[0].year
>>> rdelta = relativedelta(easter(year), today)
>>> print("Today is: %s" % today)
Today is: 2003-10-11
>>> print("Year with next Aug 13th on a Friday is: %s" % year)
Year with next Aug 13th on a Friday is: 2004
>>> print("How far is the Easter of that year: %s" % rdelta)
How far is the Easter of that year: relativedelta(months=+6)
>>> print("And the Easter of that year is: %s" % (today+rdelta))
And the Easter of that year is: 2004-04-11
```